# Python active window logger

Tags: python, pywin32

How may I log the users input in an active window such as 'example_window_name' using python? I can obtain the active window using:

```
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
print GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())
```

but how would I go about enumerating the windows until 'example_window_name' is the active one and then start logging keystrokes that the users inputs in 'example_window_name' until it becomes inactive.
This is what I got so far:

```
import win32gui
import re

class WindowMgr:
"""Encapsulates some calls to the winapi for window management"""
def __init__ (self):
    """Constructor"""
    self._handle = None

def find_window(self, class_name, window_name = None):
    """find a window by its class_name"""
    self._handle = win32gui.FindWindow(class_name, window_name)

def _window_enum_callback(self, hwnd, wildcard):
    '''Pass to win32gui.EnumWindows() to check all the opened windows'''
    if re.match(wildcard, str(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))) != None:
        self._handle = hwnd

def find_window_wildcard(self, wildcard):
    self._handle = None
    win32gui.EnumWindows(self._window_enum_callback, wildcard)

def set_foreground(self):
    """put the window in the foreground"""
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self._handle)

w = WindowMgr()
w.find_window_wildcard(".*Hello.*")
w.set_foreground()
```

Thanks for helping!